# Can we remove/clear a previously set TAG to a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering if there is a way to clear completely (instead of just overwrite) a previously set tag to a view via `view.setTag(SOME_KEY,value)` the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getTag(int)) of view.getTag(SOME_KEY) says that in case SOME_KEY is not found, the method returns `null`, i know it's possible to overwrite with some other value if we wanted to test but i want to know if it's possible to completely delete the tag once we're done with it.

Comment: write a condition to check the value is true .. once you are done with it,jump the loop condition

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but i am asking how can we remove a tag from a view (if such thing is possible) not how to write a loop condition

Comment: never tried it, but does setTag(null) work?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting null as the View tag essentially removes the one you could have set previously :

```
view.setTag(null);
```

or if you use keys

```
view.setTag(key, null);
```

Comment: ok, the first solution seems to be the right one. But the second, from my understanding, the tag is set, but not valid, isn´t it?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs, what do you mean by "not valid" ? I have to admit I've never used the second method but looking at [the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/view/View.java#1374), View stores tags in a Map, so setting null as the value for a given tag will remove the previously set value for that key. I could totally be mistaken, please feel free to edit or correct me if needed ;)

Comment: :) no problem. I don´t know, I was just wondering. For example, You set the tag like view.setTag("HELLO",null), is this tag then existing but has the value null or is it just cleared and this tag doesn´t exist anymore?

Comment: It should be the same thing. The get method for Map will return null if no value is found for a certain key, so setting null as a value has the same result for the user of the API. Internally of course, the Map is probably keeping a reference to all the keys, but they're just int so I doubt this would have a significant impact on performances. Map has a remove(key) method but I don't think that is exposed in Android for the tags Map.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i was looking for a solution more like the `remove(key)` but your comment made me dig into source of [SparseArray](http://bit.ly/1xEpFxa) where tags are stored, i could find a garbage collection method `gc()` which get rid of `DELETED`flagged entries, but for this to be triggered, `remove(key)` need to be  explicitly called.
From what i saw `remove(key)` is never called so i guess that tags will be sitting there until the associated **View** in `private static WeakHashMap<View, SparseArray<Object>> sTags;`is garbage collected thanks to the WeakHashMap reference.

Comment: And thank you for following up, I just love when answering someone else's question makes me learn something new, I wish I could +2 your question ;)